# Regex not matching correctly multiple words

Tags: java, regex

As you can see in the "Debuggex Demo" it's only matching "Drama", but I also want "Foreign", but I can't get it working. Anyone could give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

```
name":"(.*?)"}.*?,"homepage
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aLRYb_lVcGooojAu)

Comment: It looks like JSON; why would you need regex to parse it?

Comment: In this "project" I'm forbidden to use any JSON library or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use positive look-ahead and change it to:

```
name":"(.*?)"}.*?,(?=.*"homepage)
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Pshemo, even shorter one works too

```
name":"(.*?)"}(?=.*"homepage)
```

Comment: Hum... I didn't know about it. I'll read how it works now. Anyway, your regex is totally working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(?=name":"(.*?)".*,"homepage)
```